# What is nested loop in c?

Tags: c, nested-loops

**Please anybody explain this to me, because i couldn't understand this program "*right*" variable. This program couldn't fully run in my compiler.**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int answer, count, chances, right;

    for(count=1; count<11; count++){
        printf("What is %d + %d?", count,count);
        scanf("%d", &answer);

        if(answer == count+count) printf("Right!\n");
        else{
            printf("Sorry, you'r wrong.\n");
            printf("Try again.\n");
            right = 0;

            for(chances=0; chances<3 && !right; chances++){
                printf("What is %d + %d?", count, count);
                scanf("%d", answer);

                if(answer == count+count){
                    printf("Right!\n");
                    right = 1;
                }
            }
            if(!right)
                printf("The answer is %d.\n", count + count);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking, but your second `scanf` needs to include the ampersand,, `scanf("%d", &answer);`

Comment: "This program couldn't fully run in my compiler". If you are getting an compilation error then please show it.

Comment: This program output What is 1+1? from 1-10.if the answer is right it print right.But if the answer is false it give him 3 chances.But in the else part we assign right = 0.With the boolean term that means false.But in the inner for loop condition is chances<3 && !right.that means right must be true.How can be right become true.another if condition right=1(true).Then if answer is not right the last if(!right), that means right not true.I understand that.But i couldn't understand the conditional part.Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a simple math sum quiz that is asking the user for sum of same numbers from 1 to 10

The expected output is : 
What is 1 + 1?
In every single iteration of the outer loop , after questioning like this , the program waits for the user input. When the user inputs a number, it checks the sum with the input value . If the sum is right, the user is informed that the answer is right. And then then same is repeated for 2. i.e. 
What is 2 + 2?
If the user input is not right, the user is given three chances to input the right answer. After 3 consecutive wrong answers by the user , the real answer is displayed to the user and then the outer loops moves towards the next number. 
The right variable is used for a boolean value here 
I.e. 1 = true , 0 = false.
When the user answers wrong , the right variable is set to false.

Comment: In the else part right assign value 0. that means right is false.But inner for loop the conditional part is chances<3 and !right. That means right not false(true).How can be right be a true, because we assign right is false. after that we assign right=1.That means true.I understand that part is for if the answer is right.And lastly if the answer is not true than print The real answer.But i couldn't understand the conditional Right part.Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Basically the right variable is used as an inverted boolean condition in the loop. Assigning right = 0 means right is false. The condition !right will make sure that the loop will iterate only if right remains false. It means if at any loop iteration , the right changes to 1 (true) , then the loop condition will be ANDed with a false value which will break the loop immediately and the next iteration(chance) for providing another answer will not be given.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.You mostly 90% clear my queries.But i have a problem we assign right = 0.that means false.But in the second for loop condition part !right means logically not false.So, !right = not false(true).Since we assign right = 0(false).So how can be right remains false.Thanks for your time.

Comment: First of all, !right first evaluates the value of right that is false , then it inverts the condition !(false) thats is true. It doesn't mean that the value of right is changed by doing !right because it is not assigned to right variable . Right retains its value untill it is assigned another value (right = 1) . Secondly the inner loop will continue running only when right is false. Because in the loop condition !right is imposed. If right becomes 1 (true) then !right will make the loop condition false and the inner loop will break. Therefore loop will continue running till right remains false